# How to add a line in all java files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not sure if that is possible but I have a old java application projects which have 1000+ java files. I am trying to add log4j support to the application which require me to add

```
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

in every file.

Is there any way I can perform the operation using eclipse. I have tried `source->format` but that is not allowing me to add the line. Do I have to open every file and add that line?

Comment: I assume you also need to add the import statement as well, right? You could try writing a program to go through the file directory, open every .java file, and add it for you.

Comment: Looks like not a java question, but a question of writing a shell script to insert the necessary lines.

Comment: Yes I would have to add log4j import as well , That would be awesome

Comment: You're going to have to write actual logging for each file anyway though, which is going to take longer than adding the logger. Why not just add it as you add the logging?

Comment: @EvanKnowles, I thought about it, but I do have old school custom logging methods in every class which have specific signature which I can find and replace easily with logger.info() or logger.debug()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make use of **templates** in eclipse, but in this case, you need to edit each file and add it.

**Update :**

Save following content in some file-named with extension ".xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><templates><template autoinsert="true" context="java-members" deleted="false" description="adds the logger statement" enabled="true" name="logger">public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class.getName());</template></templates>
```

Press CTRL+3, Type - "templates" and choose for Templates- Java Editor as shown below

[image]

Import the file from menu from right as shown below

[image]

now go to any of your file and type "logger"in your class file and do CTRL+space , quick assist will show you the "logger" template
as shown below

[image]
and your logging statement will appear, with your class in which you are editing as shown below

[image]

Comment: template only work for new files.That is why I was checking if I do have to edit each file or not

Comment: no, no, you can check the "templates" view, e.g. you might have used the "syso" in eclipse

Answer (score 2):

You can do it programatically. Start with a filter for all your .java:

```
public class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private Set<String> filteredExtensions;
    public FileExtensionFilter() {
        filteredExtensions = new HashSet<String>();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        boolean accept = true;
        for (String filteredExtension:filteredExtensions) {
            accept = accept && !name.endsWith(filteredExtension);
        }
        return accept;
    }
    public void addFilteredExtension(String extension) {
        filteredExtensions.add(extension);
    }
}
```

Then you can look for the file using a recursive method:

```
public Set<String> searchFileBasedOnExtension(File file) {
    Set<String> extensions = new HashSet<String>();
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File f : file.listFiles(fileExtensionFilter)) {
            extensions.addAll(checkForExtensions(f));
        }
    } else {
        String extension = file.getName().substring(Math.max(file.getName().lastIndexOf('.'),0));
        extensions.add(extension);
        fileExtensionFilter.addFilteredExtension(extension);
    }
    return extensions;
}
```

Then based on the set you receive, you can iterate it, read the file to find the position to add the "import" and also find the class name, and save it into a variable to replace it for each file, since each file represents a different class.

Sample:

```
for (String s : setWithFileNames) {
 // Use BufferedReader to read the file, save the content in a String, then look inside the String the classname and the first import position.
 // Use bufferedWriter to re-write the file with the changes you made.
}
```

Hope it gives you a hand with your requirement. Best regards.

Comment: this would work. need to make sure the class name is the file name which is there most of time else parse that too

Answer (score 1):

Opening each file and adding this line would be tedious.

I am not sure if Eclipse has such thing.

But I would suggest to go for a shell script or a Java function to do this.

1. Read each file.
2. Search for the first '{' character.
3. Insert the logger statement in the line next to that.
4. You can get the class name from the file name.

I know this might not be the best solution for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not familer with shell script so I would go with java function

Comment: You can use `this.getClass()` in the logger statement to avoid the need to parse class names.

Answer (score 1):

If you have notepad ++ you can do it. Use the find replace feature for a direcory using regular expressions.

so a line starting with `public class` need to be replaced by the line and another line with the log statement.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion is to use AspectJ.  AspectJ is an extension to Java that allows you to systematically weave in extra functionality to existing classes.  You would first need to install AJDT (AspectJ development tools).  Then you need to create an Aspect like this:

```
aspect LoggingAspect {
  before (Object thiz) : execution(public * *(..)) && this(thiz) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(thiz.getClass().getName());
    logger.log("Something");
  }
}
```

The aspect above will log every execution of a public method of one of the classes that you compile.  You can certainly tweak this in many ways. Logging is one of the simplest things that AspectJ can do.  The nice thing about going down this path is that you can easily enable/disable logging from your project by commenting out 4 lines.

The main [AspectJ website](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/).  And [the AspectJ programming guide](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/index.html) is a good place to start with AspectJ.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the below command to add any line on the specific line number, Just provide the folder name it will search all the subfolders with the file extension as .java and add the line on the specific position:

```
find <Folder Path> -name "*.java" -exec sed -i '1i<Text: You want to add>' {} \;
```